# Reading different int from the same textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port, int

I´m little new to C# and i got some questions here:

I want to send my age in hex codes by serial port to a device that my pc is attached with. I have those codes but i have to read from textBox the age inputed.

For example: at textBox I enter my age (24) and each number has a hex code. So how do i read from textBox each number? I think that is what i have to do, I read number 2, send hex code, then read the second number and send hex code. Have I been clear?

**EDIT:**
Just showing u guys my code after i got awnsered. Thanks all :)

```
 private void btnConfirmaIdade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string allValue = mtxbIdade.Text;

        foreach (char c in allValue)
        {
            MandaIndadeSerial(c);
        }

    }

    public void MandaIndadeSerial(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '1':
                EnviarComando("0232363b3bde03");// send hexa code to device by serial
                    break;
```

Comment: Convert to byte array...byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("24");

Comment: Do you want it to send 24 in hex (0x18)? Or 2, then 4 in hex (0x02, 0x04), or the ASCII for "24" in hex (0x32, 0x34)?

Comment: I want to send the first number, in the example 2, then 4, but it´s not regular hex, its another code that my device read, and I know how to send the command, what I don´t understand is how i get each number from textbox separately. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach(char c in TextBox.Text)
{
  // TODO: send current number. Cast to string if needed: (string)c 
}
```

This code iterates through all numbers/characters in TextBox, left to right, and allows you to process/send them separately.

Comment: `var hex = code.ToString("X");` - You could condense this into a Linq projection eg. `TextBox.Text.Cast<Byte>().Select(x => x.ToString("X"));`

Comment: @MattDavey nice. Or just `TextBox.Text.Cast<Byte>()`. Depends on what our hero needs.

Comment: Sry but I didn´t understand =/ I´m little new to C# and programming and here is what I want: I want to send the first number, in the example 2, then 4, but it´s not regular hex, its another code that my device read, and I know how to send the command, what I don´t understand is how i get each number from textbox separately. Thanks

Comment: @JoséFlávio you need 2 and 4 as numbers or as strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
string numbers = new string[2];
numbers[0] = textbox.Text.Substring(0,1);  //first character in textbox
numbers[1] = textbox.Text.Substring(1,1);  //second character
```

Comment: What if there are 3 numbers? 4, 5, 6?

Comment: OP stated AGE...i guess there could be 3 numbers..this is an example..just showing the substring function

Comment: Lots of people live past 100 - granted not many of them use computers!

Comment: Substring is a reasonable solution, but falls over slightly when it comes to iteration. FYI I was not the person that downvoted, I don't believe this answer deserves a downvote (it's not wrong, there are just better ways)